# Should I use 'can' or 'will be able to'? "If he fixes your car tonight, you [?] drive it to school tomorrow."

Tags: grammar, differences, modal-verbs, future, can-vs-be-able

Should I change "will be able to" to "can" in the bolded sentence from the exchange below?

> A: My car broke down and I have to drive to school to pick up my daughter tomorrow. I really don't know what to do.
>
> B: Don't worry. My brother is a professional mechanic. Let's ask him for help.
> **If he fixes your car tonight, you [will be able to] drive it to school tomorrow**

I thought when referring to the future in the sub-clause of conditional 1, we should use "*will be able to*", but some native speakers say "*can*" sounds fine here for no reason, and that *can* and *can't* can be used for future tense, but they also said it doesn't sound fine in sentences like the following:

> If you fail to find a trolley, you can't move the statue into the warehouse tomorrow."

I am really confused now and I am struggling to find a clear-cut border/rule between situations where you can use "can" and "can't" for future events and those where you can't.

Comment: Both work fine, as will any "possible" modal.